# What is the easiest way in Swift to tell if a character in a String is a word character?

Tags: swift, cpu-word

In Ruby, regexp allows it to be done as simple as this:

```
x = "f"
if /^\w$/.match?(x)
    puts "yes"
else
    puts "no"
end
```

What's the simplest way to do this in Swift?

Comment: Excellent,but I tried `/regexp/` and it gave an error, is it something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Swift `Character` property [isLetter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127011-isletter):

```
let x: Character = "f"
if x.isLetter {
    print("yes")
} else {
    print("no")
}
```